# Creating Chrome extensions to hide DIV display:none; on a specific page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create my first Chrome extension.

It's basically an adblocker for specific elements, in this case - the Facebook comments section.

It works with the all_urls  but not with that specific domain.

Manifest file:

```
{
"name": "My extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://visir.is/*"], //where your script should be injected
        "css": ["style.css"] //the name of the file to be injected
    }
    ]
```

}

style.css file:

> .fbcomment {
>   display: none;
>   }

Any ideas how to correct "matches"?

I have tried `*://visir.is/*`   as specified in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns but it only works with all_urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viktor,

You are on the wrong way. Your extension should work on Facebook site, and so the matches statement in the manifest must be exactly as the following:

"matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"]

Than you need to find all the comments in the timeline (most probably by css class), detect the presence of the target site address (//visir.is/) and then hide these comments.

Because the timeline dynamically load more posts you will also need to observe the new nodes and apply your function on them too (see the example from my Chrome extension below):

```js
var obs = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
 for (var i = 0; i < mutations[0].addedNodes.length; i++) {
  if (mutations[0].addedNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
   $(mutations[0].addedNodes[i]).find(".userContentWrapper").each(function () {
    injectFBMButton($(this));
   });
  }
 }
 injectMainButton();
});
obs.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true, attributes: false, characterData: false });
```

Comment: Thanks alot!

Your right. The div I specified was inside of Facebook.

However, I found another div inside the page that I can use to block that element.

Thanks alot.